# How to add static files link on index.html in Vue 2.5?

Tags: static, vuejs2

I tried with following explanation in vue 2.5 it does not work. But in version vue 2.4.2 working fine.

"Real" Static Assets
In comparison, files in static/ are not processed by Webpack at all: they are directly copied to their final destination as-is, with the same filename. You must reference these files using absolute paths, which is determined by joining build.assetsPublicPath and build.assetsSubDirectory in config.js.

As an example, with the following default values:

// config/index.js

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  build: {
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static'
  }
}
```

Any file placed in static/ should be referenced using the absolute URL /static/[filename]. If you change assetSubDirectory to assets, then these URLs will need to be changed to /assets/[filename].
Any suggestion for vue 2.5.2 ?

Comment: Only the version of Vue changed? Not of the Vue-cli?

Comment: just changed the  vue version from package.json and installed it using npm install